# How can sort differently in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this :

***SELECT put_id,ut_id,cm_tx,da,un FROM TA***

```
ut_id  | put_id  |        cm_tx             | da         |   un
 ------|---------|--------------------------|------------|--------
 21    | 21      |  was good                | 1523190974 |  Jonah
 22    | 21      |  thx                     | 1523197793 |  Sara
 23    | 23      |  that was good post      | 1523201196 |  Tom
 24    | 24      |  not good                | 1523208390 |  Lucas
 25    | 24      |  not good??              | 1523718726 |  Stephen
 26    | 24      |  why u said not good?    | 1523718805 |  Stephen
 27    | 24      |  tell me why u said?     | 1523718886 |  Stephen
```

And what I want :

```
ut_id  | put_id  |        cm_tx             | da         |   un
 ------|---------|--------------------------|------------|--------
 21    | 21      |  was good                | 1523190974 |  Jonah
 22    | 21      |  thx                     | 1523197793 |  Sara
 23    | 23      |  that was good post      | 1523201196 |  Tom
 24    | 24      |  not good                | 1523208390 |  Lucas
 27    | 24      |  tell me why u said?     | 1523718886 |  Stephen
 26    | 24      |  why u said not good?    | 1523718805 |  Stephen
 25    | 24      |  not good??              | 1523718726 |  Stephen
```

> (in fact, I want to sort the only " ut_id != put_id ") ORDER BY da AND put_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried order by put_id asc, put_id desc

Comment: yes but that's not work

Comment: which is the logic for this order by  ???

Comment: I want sort ut_id != put_id desc

Comment: The logic behind the ordering is not clear, at least not to me. `order by ut_id != put_id` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: my means order by  " ut_id != put_id desc "

Comment: this means the user be a chat with a friend and the first reply go down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from your desired output, you want to sort by put_id, then by whether ut_id = put_id, then by date descending. You could achieve this with:

```
SELECT put_id,ut_id,cm_tx,date,un FROM TA ORDER BY put_id ASC, IF(ut_id = put_id, 0, 1) ASC, date DESC
```

Output:

```
put_id ut_id   cm_tx                 date           un  
21     21      was good              1523190974     Jonah
21     22      thx                   1523197793     Sara
23     23      that was good post    1523201196     Tom
24     24      not good              1523208390     Lucas
24     27      tell me why u said?   1523718886     Stephen
24     26      why u said not good?  1523718805     Stephen
24     25      not good??            1523718726     Stephen
```

Comment: Thanks, u solved the problem exactly